# Post form to more URLs

Tags: php, javascript, forms

is it there any way to post a form to more URLs? 
I need it in javascript..
For example: I've got 2 documents: 1.php and 2.php.. I want the form to post data to the both of these files, but go to the 1.php..
Do you know any way?

Comment: You can use AJAX and send the data to `2.php` on form `submit`.

Comment: You could also do something like `ob_start(); include('2.php'); ob_end_clean();` in the 1.php file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a form with the action "1.php" and jQuery.

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var $th = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '2.php',  // note: edited by Ryan
        data: $th.serialize(),
        success: function(){
            $th.submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I re-evaluated my selected answer after the years  and I understand I was totally wrong with my choice of answer. For the sake of this community, I accept your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript, yes

You'll want to make one call using the [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) function available in JavaScript to make an AJAX call to the php.2 script. The second call can then be done using `document.forms["FORMNAME"].submit()`.

Libraries like [jQuery's Ajax functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) make it easier to use the XMLHttpRequest function. See the jquery.get(), jquery.post(), and jquery.ajax() (a.k.a $.get(), $.post() and $.ajax()) function documentation

Here are a few guides to doing AJAX calls using jQuery's $.post() and $.ajax() functions.

- (http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery-3/)
- (http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/)
- (http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=256503.0)
- (http://www.ryancoughlin.com/2008/11/04/use-jquery-to-submit-form/)

Also here is an example framework of how this can be coded up:

```
    <form id="exampleform" name="exampleform" action="1.php">
    ...
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function submitForm()
      {
        ... // set up vars for $.post() call

        // Make the post call for the 2.php
        $.post( ... );

        // Submit the form for 1.php
        document.forms["exampleform"].submit();
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All above solution should work, but remember ajax is only alowed in same domain posting. This mean you are on http://example.com, you can only post to example.com/etc or sub.example.com

If you really want to cross domain posting, you should create an empty ifram as target (id="iframeid") then change the target of the form to it:

```
<form target="_iframeid" action=""/>
```

After that you can use javascript to post to one page, and then change action url and repost again

Answer (score -2):

the quick and dirty way to do this is to post the form to one script which will in turn post it to a second script.

Comment: Yea man.. I was thinking about that..
I think i will use this method :-D

Comment: I'm far from an expert so I am curious if there is something wrong with this approach.

Comment: -1, just setup the form to submit to `1.php`, then attach an `onsubmit` handler for the form that will send an AJAX POST to `2.php` . +1 to ekrembk, I believe his answer should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: I agree, ekrembk provides a much better solution than mine.