# Need form to post to two off-server URLs then redirect with PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, forms, post

I have a form that needs to be submitted to two separate URLs: one being a Google Spreadsheet to store the data and the other being an off-site ASP form handler script. When I set the form action to either URL it works perfectly. However, I need it to submit to both URLs then redirect to a simple success.html page. If they weren't external scripts I could do so easily with AJAX ([see article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024490/post-form-to-more-urls)) but that isn't an option because of cross domain issues. Here is my code:

```
<form name="apply-now-form" action="somescript.php" method="POST" id="apply-now-form"   class="apply-now-form">
   <label class="form-label" >Full Name</label>
     <input name="FirstName" id="FirstName" type="text">
     <input name="LastName" id="LastName" type="text" >
   <label>Phone Number</label>
     <input name="ResidencePhone" id="ResidencePhone" type="text" > 
   <label>Email Address</label>
     <input name="EmailAddress" id="EmailAddress" type="email" >
</form>
```

The ASP script handles the success redirect so I reckon it should be submitted to that one second. Is there a way, using cURL or otherwise, to send unaltered form data to multiple URLs using PHP? Or Javascript if that's an option? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform this with CURL.

```
1- Create the data array and serialize it:

$fields = array( $k => $v,...);

 foreach ($fields as $key => $value) {
        $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }
 rtrim($fields_string, '&');
```

2- Send the data to Google:

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://googlesite');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
```

3- Send the data to the ASP:

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://aspweb');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
```

4- Redirect

```
 header('Location: http://successpage')
```

I think that's all.

Comment: Would I need to list out all the fields from my form in a `$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];` format in the `$fields = array( $k => $v,...);` portion? Sorry, new to PHP.

Comment: Yes, you have to set the values you want to pass to Google and to the ASP page: $fields = array( 'FirstName' => $POST['FirstName'],...) and so on.

Comment: OK so it is very close except the data is not parsing correctly. Both URLs are receiving data but it is coming through as "undefined". If you send it with a simple action="googlesite.com" it parses correctly. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You named it... you have to use curl!
A nice place to start could be PHP cURL manual: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php